# Count number of unique adjacent cells in a matrix

Tags: python, performance, matrix

I want to write an algorithm to count how many islands are in a given matrix. Consider for example:

```
A = [
        [1, 2, 1, 3], 
        [2, 2, 3, 2],
        [3, 3, 2, 3]
    ]
```

Directly adjacent (north, south, east, west, but not diagonally) numbers constitute an island, in this example matrix we have 9.

I've written the following code which works and performs fine. Any suggestions on how could I write this more cleanly and to make it work even faster?

```
def clean_neighbours(matrix, this_row, this_col):
    cell_value = matrix[this_row][this_col]
    if cell_value == 0:
        return

    matrix[this_row][this_col] = 0
    number_of_rows = len(matrix)
    number_of_columns = len(matrix[0])

    for shift in (
        (-1,0), (1,0), (0,-1), (0,1)
    ):
        row, col = [x+y for x,y in zip((this_row, this_col), shift)]
        if (row >= 0 and row < number_of_rows) and (
            col >= 0 and col < number_of_columns
        ):
            if matrix[row][col] == cell_value:
                clean_neighbours(matrix, row, col)

def count_adjacent_islands(matrix):
    number_of_islands = 0
    for row_index, row in enumerate(matrix):
        for column_index, _ in enumerate(row):
            if matrix[row_index][column_index] != 0:
                number_of_countries += 1
                clean_neighbours(matrix, row_index, column_index)
    return number_of_countries

import random
A = [ [random.randint(-1000,1000) for e in range(0,1000)] for e in range(0,1000) ]
print(count_adjacent_islands(A))
```

Comment: Please don't edit your question so that it invalidates current answers.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*. Also, if you want to delete your question when it has been answered, the process for that is a bit more complicated. See ["If I flag my question with a request to delete it, what will happen?" in this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/213556)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## bug

in `count_adjacent_islands`, `number_of_islands = 0` should be `number_of_countries = 0`

## mutate original argument

Most of the time, it's a bad idea to change any of the arguments to a function unless explicitly expected. So you better take a copy of the matrix first:

```
matrix_copy = [row[:] for row in matrix]
```

## tuple unpacking

instead of `for shift in ((-1,0), (1,0), (0,-1), (0,1)):`, you can do `for dx, dy in ((-1, 0), (1, 0), (0, -1), (0, 1)):`, then `row, col = [x+y for x,y in zip((this_row, this_col), shift)]` can be expressed a lot clearer: `row, col = x + dx, y + dy`

## continue

instead of keep nesting `if` conditions, you can break out of that iteration earlier if the conditions are not fulfilled

```
for row_index, row in enumerate(matrix):
    for column_index, _ in enumerate(row):
        if matrix[row_index][column_index] != 0:
            number_of_islands += 1
            clean_neighbours(matrix, row_index, column_index)
```

can become:

```
for row_index, row in enumerate(matrix_copy):
    for column_index, _ in enumerate(row):
        if matrix_copy[row_index][column_index] == 0:
            continue
        number_of_islands += 1
        clean_neighbours2(matrix_copy, row_index, column_index)
```

saving 1 level of indentation on the code that actually does the lifting. This is not much in this particular case, but with larger nested conditions, this can make things a lot clearer, and save a lot of horizontal screen estate

## recursion

If there are some larger islands, you will run into the recursion limit. Better would be to transform this to a queue and a loop

```
from collections import deque
def clean_neighbours2(matrix, x, y):
    cell_value = matrix[x][y]
    if cell_value == 0:
        return

    matrix[x][y] = 0

    queue = deque([(x,y)])

    while queue:
        x, y = queue.pop()
        for dx, dy in ((-1, 0), (1, 0), (0, -1), (0, 1)):
            row, col = x + dx, y + dy
            if (
                0 <= row < len(matrix)
                and 0 <= col < len(matrix[0])
                and not matrix[row][col] == 0
            ):
                continue
            if matrix[row][col] == cell_value:
                queue.append((row, col))
                matrix[row][col] = 0

def count_adjacent_islands2(matrix):
    matrix_copy = [row[:] for row in matrix]
    number_of_islands = 0
    for row_index, row in enumerate(matrix_copy):
        for column_index, _ in enumerate(row):
            if matrix_copy[row_index][column_index] == 0:
                continue
            number_of_islands += 1
            clean_neighbours2(matrix_copy, row_index, column_index)
    return number_of_islands
```

For the sample data you provided, this code took 3s compared to 4s for the original on my machine

---

## alternative approach

Using `numba` and `numpy`, and a slight rewrite to accomodate for numba compatibilities:

```
from numba import jit
import numpy as np

@jit()
def clean_neighbours_jit(matrix, x, y):
    cell_value = matrix[x, y]
    if cell_value == 0:
        return

    matrix[x, y] = 0

    queue = [(x, y)]
    row_length, column_length = matrix.shape

    while queue:
        x, y = queue.pop()
        for dx, dy in ((-1, 0), (1, 0), (0, -1), (0, 1)):
            row, col = x + dx, y + dy
            if (
                not 0 <= row < row_length
                or not 0 <= col < column_length
                or matrix[row, col] != cell_value
            ):
                continue
            queue.append((row, col))
            matrix[row, col] = 0

@jit()
def count_adjacent_islands_jit(matrix):
    matrix_copy = matrix.copy()
    number_of_islands = 0
    row_length, column_length = matrix_copy.shape
    for row_index in range(row_length):
        for column_index in range(column_length):
            if matrix_copy[row_index, column_index] == 0:
                continue
            number_of_islands += 1
            clean_neighbours_jit(matrix_copy, row_index, column_index)
    return number_of_islands
```

This expects a numpy array as `matrix`, (for example: `count_adjacent_islands_jit(np.array(A))`) but does the job in about 200 to 300ms, (about 80ms spent on converting `A` to an `np.array`), so more than 10x speedup.

Comment: >about 80ms spent on converting A to an np.array. How did you carried out this analysis?

Comment: Thank you very much for your review. Great ideas, I haven't work with numba before, quite impressive!

Comment: The 80ms comes from comparing `A2 = np.array(A); %timeit count_adjacent_islands_jit(A2)` versus `%timeit count_adjacent_islands_jit(np.array(A))` (in a jupyter notebook). And numba is impressive indeed. Only the shift to numpy seemed to slow the code, and jitting the original method didn't give any advantage